# Multiclass penalty in Neverwinter Nights?

Tags: neverwinter-nights

I have a human fighter who is level 4. I noticed there were quite a bit of big chests that I was passing up due to not being able to pick locks. So I put 1 level into rogue and all points into unlock. So now I'm a level 3 fighter and a level 1 rogue. Is this going to cause me a multiclass penalty, and if so is that a big deal?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, I reread the NWN wiki about [multiclass penalty](http://nwn.wikia.com/wiki/Multiclass_penalty). So the penalty is defined as anytime character's classes are not nearly the same level. You do get a racially favored class that does not count in the split.

My racially favored class is a fighter (due to me being a human, and it being the highest), so this doesn't count towards it. Which leaves just the Rogue Level which has no other class to be even with. Making me have no multiclass penalty. I would have to take another class and then level it up total 3 times to get a multiclass penalty.

Comment: This is correct.  Also note that if you take any prestige classes, they do not count towards a multiclass penalty

Comment: Also don't you not get a multiclass penalty even if you weren't a fighter because you're human and thats their racial trait?

Comment: @Shykin not sure exactly what racial trait is, is it racially favored class? If so for humans that is the highest class level you have.